# ESP8266 _make http request

Tags: sockets, esp8266, micropython

I'm trying to transfer some data to web so what I did is creating 3 files 
the first one is info.php which will allows me to fill database with values 
the second file is tryjson.php which will allows me to extract specific values from database

and the problem is on the third file which will allows me to send http request via web browser in order to call the first file "Info.php" or the second one tryjson.php
the problem that I keep getting error at this line

```
ai = socket.getaddrinfo("http://192.168.8.100/info.php?request=testingg", 80)
```

Code is bellow

```
try:

import usocket as socket

except:

import socket

import ussl as ssl

s = socket.socket()
ai = socket.getaddrinfo("http://192.168.8.100/info.php?request=testingg", 80)
print("Bind address info:", ai)
conn.request("HEAD","/info.php?request=sameur")
res = conn.getresponse()
 print (res.status, res.reason)
 # Result: 
print("200 OK")
#print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```

What should I do to get over this ?

B.R

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) for `getaddrinfo()`. It says the method takes these arguments:

```
socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0)
```

You're passing it a URL, not a hostname. You should be calling it like this:

```
ai = socket.getaddrinfo("192.168.8.100", 80)
```

Comment: the problem that I want to excute this statement  at with that IP  and PORT  : "/info.php?request=testingg"

Comment: The problem is you're calling socket.getaddrinfo() with the wrong arguments. It does not take a URL. It only takes a hostname. You're using it incorrectly. That's why you're getting an error.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion or another methode to do it?